# How can I inject 'for in' loops in a function?

Tags: r, loops

I learned `function` and `for in` loop and I'm trying to inject loop into the function, so that I can use looping conveniently or inject loops in another loops.
But it doesn't work.

I'll show you the code.

```
for(year in c(2016:2018)){x<-c(x,paste("tax",year))}
```

with this, I succeeded making sequence of `[tax 2016, tax 2017, tax 2018]`.

Further, I'm trying to make a function that can easily produce `[tax 2016, tax 2017, tax 2018, tax 2019, ...]`

so I wrote code like this

`F=function(a){for(year in c(2016:a)){x<-c(x,paste("tax",year))}}`

and then

`y=F(2020)`

but the value "y" turns out to be
`[NULL(empty)]`

What's the problem? Is it impossible to inject loops in a function? Or are there other keys?

--

Comment: Your function, as it's written, doesn't return anything, so `function` will by default return `NULL`. `paste` is already vectorized so `function(a){paste("tax",2016:a)}` will achieve the same result.

Comment: F is short for `FALSE`, it's not a reserved word but using it is very dangerous, better never to use `F` for `FALSE` AND never to override `F`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions for your code:

- Error: you never define `x` in the function, so it must be finding an `x` outside of the function, generally a bad thing (and can be very hard to troubleshoot, as you're finding out); a quick-hack workaround is to define `x <- c()` or in a more "declarative" fashion, `x <- character(0)` before the `for` loop;
- Problem (though not error) as AndyBarbour pointed out: a `for` loop returns nothing, so your function also returns nothing. You need to `return` something.
- Speed/code-efficiency: this doesn't need a `for` loop, try `paste("tax", 2016:2018)`;
- Programming: you might want to learn to be defensive in your programming, assuming the calling user is evil or makes a lot of mistakes; what do you expect to happen with `F(2)`? Should it return decreasing `"tax 2016", "tax 2015", "tax 2014", ..., "tax 3", "tax 2"`?
- Programming: hard-coding constants in your function might be too limiting, you could offer an optional argument in the function declaration for a starting point, such as `F <- function(a, start = 2016L)`;
- Style: no need for `c` in `c(2016:a)`, just do `2016:a`, it adds nothing here.

Different variants of the same function, with this in mind:

```r
F <- function(yr, start = 2016L) {
  if (yr >= start) return(paste("tax", start:yr))
  return(character(0))
}
F <- function(yr) start = 2016L) {
  x <- character(0)
  if (y >= start) {
    for (y in yr:start) x <- c(x, paste("tax", y))
  }
  return(x)
}
```